# keras can not detect gpu

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, nvidia

I have problem with my keras-gpu.

I install keras-gpu with Anaconda. 
My laptop have two gpus. One is nVidia GTX950M, the other is Intel integrated graphics.When I run these testing codes,

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

the console shows:

```
2019-01-19 09:34:15.794202: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2019-01-19 09:34:16.303681: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 950M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.124
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.65GiB
2019-01-19 09:34:16.310913: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-01-19 09:34:17.879659: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-01-19 09:34:17.884168: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0
2019-01-19 09:34:17.886646: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2019-01-19 09:34:17.890046: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1400 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 950M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

It seems that my nVidia gpu is working.
But I use my keras-gpu, and run the following codes.

```
x_train,y_train = dataGenerate()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(units=5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model = multi_gpu_model(model, 2)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer = 'sgd')

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=200,batch_size=10)
```

I check the task manager, and only my Intel Integrated Graphics works.
I have tried

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"
```

but it's still not working. And I tried to add these lines to my codes,

```
model = multi_gpu_model(model, 2)
model.summary()
```

the console shows:

```
ValueError: To call `multi_gpu_model` with `gpus=2`, 
we expect the following devices to be available: ['/cpu:0', '/gpu:0', '/gpu:1']. 
However this machine only has: ['/cpu:0', '/gpu:0']. Try reducing `gpus`.
```

The gpu0 is my Intel graphics. So it turns out that my keras-gpu can not detect my nvidia gpu. 
It doesn't make sense. How can it be that my tensorflow can detect the gpu but keras can not.
I have working with this problem for so many days and it drives me crazy.
Please help me out.

Comment: I also try mnist training using tensorflow, and I check my task manager, which shows that nVidia gpu does work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do makes no sense, TensorFlow does not support Intel GPUs, only NVIDIA CUDA GPUs, your Intel GPU is not usable in TensorFlow, so it will always only see one GPU.

To use multi GPU, you need at least 2 NVIDIA CUDA GPUs.